# How to determine if an app is running on Android M (Developer Preview)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Note: this question was asked for the Android M developer preview, not the official Android 6.0.

android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT returns 22 on Android M (22 is the api level for LOLLIPOP_MR1). How are we supposed to check whether the app runs on Android M? I had something like this in mind but that obviously doesn't work:

```
public boolean isAndroidMOrHigher() {
    return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.MNC;
}
```

Why do I need this? E.g. to check whether I need to request permissions because with Android M there's a new permission model.

I could do this:

```
public boolean isAndroidMOrHigher() {
    return "M".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
}
```

But that seems to be a hack IMO.

There are really two questions:

- What's the cleanest way to do this?
- Is this a bug or is this supposed to be like that?

Comment: If you're not targeting API 23 yet, you don't need to request permissions (legacy apps will just get empty data back if the permission is removed).

Comment: I do target Android M so I need to request the permissions or some functions won't work.

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/05/supporting-m-developer-preview-previous-versions.html

Comment: If you post this as an answer you'll get some reputation ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's the cleanest way to do this?

**UPDATE**: Google code samples show a different
option: `"MNC".equals(Build.VERSION.CODENAME)`.

Personally, [I'm looking at `PREVIEW_SDK_INT`, if it exists](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/05/supporting-m-developer-preview-previous-versions.html):

```
static private boolean putMarzipanInYourPiePlateBingo() {
  boolean result=false;

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    try {
      Field f=Build.VERSION.class.getField("PREVIEW_SDK_INT");

      if (f.getInt(null)>0) {
        result=true;
      }
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
      // no problem, must really be API 22
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      // ummm... this shouldn't happen
    }
  }

  return(result);
}
```

This is more cumbersome than your `M` check. However, if Google decides to play yet more games (e.g., change `Build.VERSION.RELEASE`), I think this approach will be more stable.

> Is this a bug or is this supposed to be like that?

[One man's bug is another man's working-as-intended](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2227).

Comment: Suppose I need to use PREVIEW_SDK_INT only in case of new Android versions, is it safe to use something like this without reflection  : `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && Build.VERSION.PREVIEW_SDK_INT != 0 )... `? Or such a thing could crash on versions that are older than M ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I *think* that will hold up, as the `Build.VERSION.PREVIEW_SDK_INT != 0` will only be evaluated on new-enough devices for the field to exist. It's certainly something to test. It's not the sort of thing that ought to break on a per-manufacturer basis (I can't imagine any manufacturer having a hidden field of that name in that location pre-M), so if you try it and it doesn't crash, it should be OK. Sorry for not being more definitive, but I'm short on sleep... :-)

Comment: OK tested on old emulator. Seems to work fine without crashing. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

A much shorter and standardized approach for this check

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M )
```

This is also the official code suggested by Android Developers.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Comment: The question was asked for the preview version of Android M which didn't have an API version yet, hence the question. Your answer is correct for the official Android M but not for the developer preview version.